# Why does my swig template not render in my MEAN web app?

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

I am trying to learn [the MEAN stack](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/49262866911/the-mean-stack-mongodb-expressjs-angularjs-and) along with [Swig templates](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/). I’m coding from scratch, as I tried a MEAN framework but it generated a lot of files and it was too much for me to begin with.

Currently my Swig template index.html does not render the HTML. This is the output I am getting:

```
{% include 'header.html' %} 
<br>Welcome to my test website
```

where as I am expecting following

```
This is coming from Header
<br>Welcome to my test website
```

Why is it not rendering?

Following is my folder structure:

```
--config
 -config.js
--node_modules
 -* //modules installed via npm link
--public
 -header.html
 -index.html
-package.json
-routes.js
-server.js
```

Below is the content of each file

**config.js**

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

module.exports = {
    dburl: 'mongodb://localhost/test',
    port: port,
    templateEngine: 'swig'
}
```

**header.html**

```
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p> This is coming from Header</p>
```

**index.html**

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
<p>Welcome to my test website</p>
</body>
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Rukmaj Chandavar",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "*",
        "mongoose": "*",
        "angular": "*",
        "swig": "*",
        "consolidate": "*"
    }
}
```

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('*',function(req, res){
        res.send('index.html');
    });
}
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var config = require('./config/config');
var swig = require('swig');
var cons = require('consolidate');

mongoose.connect(config.dburl);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');


require('./routes') (app);

app.listen(config.port);
console.log('MeriDawat running on port ' + config.port)
```

Following are the version numbers of installed node modules

```
angular@1.2.18
consolidate@0.10.0
express@4.4.3
mongoose@3.8.12
passport@0.2.0
swig@1.3.2
```

I would appreciate any help in troubleshooting this to help me move forward. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention `mean init` — are you using http://mean.io/?

Comment: no I am not in this example, however when I used it earlier it generated lot of files which was too much for me. So I started from scratch with a simple project.

Comment: So what *are* you using that provides the `mean init` command?

Comment: this question is not about mean init, it is about unable to render swig template using node and express. It was just a background information, there is **no relation to mean.io whatsoever**.

Comment: ah, I see. I’ve edited your question to hopefully make that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the offending line, in routes.js:

```
res.send('index.html');
```

[`res.send()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send) just sends the contents of the file back in the HTTP response.

To render a template and send the rendered results back, you want [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render) instead:

```
res.render('index.html')
```

Comment: I had tried this before and tried once again, alas result is still the same.

Comment: it appears the error is somewhere else as I tried commenting  the response line itself i.e, `res.send('index.html')`  and also lines in server.js corresponding to view, still the outcome is same. It appears the application is reading from somewhere else OR considering /public as document root and rendering index.html. In any case the problem persists. Any help in pointing the incorrect line of code will be great

Comment: It appears the error was with `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` commented this line everything is working fine. Now further I am trying to insert a link for stylesheet in header.html, however it does not get loaded. So, now the static folder is broken, could someone help me fix this

Comment: @Rukmaj: Aha! Yes, of course. Your templates shouldn’t be kept in a folder that you pass to `express.static`. That folder is just for files that should be served directly from your app to end users.

Comment: @Rukmaj: “Now further I am trying to insert a link for stylesheet in header.html, however it does not get loaded. So, now the static folder is broken, could someone help me fix this”. Yup — ask another question!

Comment: separating the folders helped fix both the issues, thanks now everything is working as expected.

Comment: @Rukmaj: you’re most welcome. Feel free to add an answer documenting your actual solution: you’re very much allowed to answer your own question here, and it may help other people in the future to see it documented clearly (as well as reinforcing your learning in your own mind).